# Custom User Model per App

Tags: django

We upgrade an django app from 1.5 to 1.7

I am unsure if the update to [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model) is a good idea in my case.

Since there is only one `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings, only **one** app can be the "winner".

If you have several apps, this does not work.

What to do, if several apps want to store custom information per user?

Example:

`employeeapp` wants to store `salary` per user. And `skillsapp` wants to store `skill_level` per user.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "profile" models with 1-to-1 field to the `User`:

**employeeapp/models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
```

**skillsapp/models.py**

```
class Handyman(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    skill_level = models.IntegerField()
```

And then you can access these "profiles" as simple as:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='me')
user.employee.salary
user.handyman.skill_level
```

If you want to create "profile" instances automatically then use the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-save) signal for `User` sender.

Comment: Why not use inheritance? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: At DB level it will be the same solution (master table for the `User` parent and two tables for `Employee` and `Handyman` children).  But this will be much more complicated python code.